# Aligning excel cells with varying number of decimals

Tags: excel, format, decimal

I have the following numbers:

```
111     27    21     239
634    1714    2    33440
-3.1  48.72  -85.3  269.88
-0.43  4.82  -36.78 35.14
```

I would like to obtain the following format (centering cells and aligning to the unit)

```
111      27     21      239
634    1714      2    33440
 -3.10   48.72 -85.30   269.88
 -0.43    4.82 -36.78    35.14
```

I have tried with the following custom format: ????.?? . However, I don't obtain what I exactly need:

```
  111.        27.     21.    239.  
  634.      1714.      2.   33440.  
-   3.1       48.72 -  85.3      269.88
-    .43       4.82 -  36.78      35.14
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Would formatting each to 2dp achieve the majority of the benefit you're after? Thinking purely 80:20 here - but does the lack of decimals on some figures give you additional value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split with Text To Columns and `.` as delimiter. Right align the integers, left align the decimals and insert a (narrow) column between the two with just `.`.